# Trying to chronologically print events that occur

Tags: c#, events, simulator

I'm trying to build a traffic simulator with three primary events:

1. a light change
2. a car entering an intersection
3. a car departing the intersection

The program should output a combination of events in accordance to user input...but for some reason, it is not working. the output will repeatedly spout out one event (arriveeast, for example), or only two events, instead of a combination of several in accordance to user input, like so;

```
arriveeast
arriveeast
arrivenorth
lighteast
```

etc...

I was wondering if anyone would be so kind as to point out what I'm overlooking? I'm relatively new to this and I'm having a hard time finding people to bounce ideas off of.  I think the loop is failing, but I cant see how/where and I'm not getting error messages...

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace sim
{
    public static class Simulation
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            double average; // average of all trials
            double interArrivalEast, interArrivalNorth; // Arrival times between cars coming from East and North
            double onTimeEast, onTimeNorth, onTimeBoth; // Green light on times for East and North lights as well as both lights
            double lastLeaveEast, lastLeaveNorth; // Last time a car left from the East and North
            double totalTime; // Total time for all events to occur
            double sum = 0;
            double u; // Uniformly distributed random variable
            int numEvents; // Total number of events possible
            Event temp = new Event("", 0);
            Random rand1; // Random seed
            PriorityQueue<Event> events; // Priority queue of events
            Queue east, north; // Queue of cars approaching from the East and North
            bool eastLight, northLight;
            east = new Queue();
            north = new Queue();
            rand1 = new Random();
            Console.Write("Please enter the inter-arrival time for cars approaching from the East: ");
            interArrivalEast = -(Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()) * Math.Log(u = rand1.NextDouble()));
            Console.Write("Please enter the inter-arrival time for cars approaching from the North: ");
            interArrivalNorth = -(Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()) * Math.Log(u));
            Console.Write("Please enter the green light on time for cars approaching from the East: ");
            onTimeEast = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Please enter the green light on time for cars approaching from the North: ");
            onTimeNorth = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            onTimeBoth = onTimeEast + onTimeNorth;
            numEvents = Convert.ToInt32((interArrivalEast * 50 / onTimeEast) + (interArrivalNorth * 50 / onTimeNorth) + (onTimeEast * 50 / 3) + (onTimeNorth * 50 / 3) + 100);
            events = new PriorityQueue<Event>(numEvents);
            totalTime = ((50 * onTimeEast) + (50 * onTimeNorth));

            for (double i = 0; i < totalTime; i += interArrivalEast)
            {
                events.Add(new Event("arriveeast", i));
            }
            for (double j = 0; j < totalTime; j += interArrivalNorth)
            {
                events.Add(new Event("arrivenorth", j));
            }
            for (double k = 0; k < totalTime; k += onTimeBoth)
            {
                events.Add(new Event("lighteast", k));
                for (double l = k; l < k + onTimeBoth; l += 3)
                    events.Add(new Event("leaveeast", l));
            }
            for (double m = onTimeEast; m < totalTime; m += onTimeBoth)
            {
                events.Add(new Event("lightnorth", m));
                for (double n = m; n < m + onTimeBoth; n += 3)
                    events.Add(new Event("leavenorth", n));
            }
            for (int o = 0; o < 1000; o++)
            {
                while (!events.Empty())
                {
                    temp = events.Front();
                    switch (temp.EType)
                    {

                        case "arriveeast":
                            east.Enqueue(temp.Time);
                            break;
                        case "arrivenorth":
                            north.Enqueue(temp.Time);
                            break;
                        case "leaveeast":
                            east.Dequeue();
                            break;
                        case "leavenorth":
                            north.Dequeue();
                            break;
                        case "lighteast":
                            eastLight = true;
                            northLight = false;
                            break;
                        case "lightnorth":
                            northLight = true;
                            eastLight = false;
                            break;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", Convert.ToString(o), temp.EType);
                    events.Remove();
                }
                sum += temp.Time;
            }
            average = sum / 1000;
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(average));
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Too.. much.. code... Please narrow down the code to the broken part and describe *exactly* what "isn't working".

Comment: Oop. sorry, tried to scale it down. Was afraid of not giving enough information.

Comment: I can appreciate that, but I don't usually feel like reading an entire program to find the error in one function :).

Comment: Scaling down is good, but there still needs to be a complete, debuggable code example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i'm not really sure how to narrow this down further-- i'm pretty sure this is where the error is, but given how narrow the sample is, it isn't really executable for testing. :/

Comment: The way to narrow down further is to not try to preserve what your program is intended to do — replace parts that aren't the problem with stubs (for example: replace user input with a constant) so that you have a program that's shorter but still demonstrates the problem, even if it isn't useful for anything. Doing this can help you understand the problem yourself, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your problem can be narrowed down to:

First you add all of your `arriveeast`'s

```
for (double i = 0; i < totalTime; i += interArrivalEast)
{
      events.Add(new Event("arriveeast", i));
}
```

Then you add the `norths`...

Then in your loop you write them out in order:

```
temp = events.Front();
//switch
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", Convert.ToString(o), temp.EType);
```

your `Console.WriteLine` doesn't seem to care what happens in the `switch` statement, it's just writing them out as they came in.